# How to convert the .fla to html5

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, flash

I got a old flash file used on an website. it was coded using ActionScript 2.0. I need to convert it to html5, but the new Adobe Flash bugs converting, because it just supports ActionScript 3.0.

What could i do?

Thank you

Comment: if you still have access to the .fla you can probably find an older flash trial somewhere just get to the old code. Then it's matter of porting it to js. I haven't used Flash in a while, but the CreateJS toolkit should help export assets/animations

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it easily because there are different languages being used. Most powerful can be using `Flash CC` but without manual editing you can't do this.

Comment: you can't convert directly flash > html5 if you fla use actionscript. In this case you must convert code to js yourself